# how to load modules in different folders

Tags: lua

I have following folder structure

--**folder1**
------main.lua
------**sub_folder**
---------func1.lua
--**folder2**
------func2.lua

I want to load `func1.lua` and `func2.lua` in `main.lua` by `require` command

PS:what does the init.lua in a folder do

Comment: If you can use `dofile` instead of `require`, you can supply explicit paths.

Comment: RE PS: `require` by default look for a `init.lua` file if you try to require a folder. Ex if you have a file `foo/init.lua`, then `require("foo")` will run it.

Answer (score 2):

In vanilla lua, you'd load them like this:

```
local func1 = loadfile "sub_folder/func1.lua"
local func2 = loadfile "../folder2/func2.lua"
```

See: [Pil Chapter 8](http://www.lua.org/pil/8.html)

If you're using Lua embedded in some other application (i.e, a game, software, etc.), then you need to let us know what this is, or we can't help you. This goes for your P.S question as well. But generally, `init.lua` is usually the first file to be executed, i.e, it'll load other files, etc.

Answer (score 2):

The `func1.lua` is easily loaded via

```
require 'sub_folder.func1'
```

because `sub_folder` is in the same folder as `main.lua`.

For `func2.lua`, there is no way to tell `require` to search "one level up", so you must tell Lua how to find the required modules. This can be done at least two ways:

1. via `LUA_PATH` environment variable:

   - append `path/to/folder2/?.lua` to it, then `main.lua` can do `require "func2"`.
   - OR append `path/to/parent-of-folder2/?.lua` to it, then `main.lua` can do `require "folder2.func2"`.
2. by editing `package.path` in your script:

   ```
   package.path = package.path .. ';../?.lua'
   require 'func2'
   ```

   or

   ```
   package.path = package.path .. ';../../?.lua'
   require 'folder2.func2'
   ```

The first method is more "permanent" since the setting is in the OS environment; it will work even if you move `folder1` to some other place on your system, without moving `folder2`. The second method is dynamic so it will work regardless of where you place your folder structure, i.e., if `folder2` is always sibling folder of `folder1` the method 2 works, method 1 fails (or requires that you edit the LUA_PATH).